# How to ignore br tag in mobile view

Tags: css

I have some line of code where I need to use 
 tag for desktop view only but ignore it in the mobile view. The code is

```
     <p class="email-message">
        <spring:theme code="text.guestuserorder.status.email.confirmation" text="Your order number can be found in your confirmation email"/>   
        <c:if test="${resendEmailToggle eq 'true'}">
        <br><span role="link" tabindex="0" class="resend-confirmation-mail-link mobile-alignment"><spring:theme code="lost.your.confirmation.mail.text" text="Lost your confirmation mail?"/>
              <span class="sr-only">This action will open modal</span>
            </span>                           
        </c:if>
    </p>
```

Comment: There is no code in your question. Please, provide some.

Comment: Consider Adding the html tag too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into your CSS:

```
@media(max-width: 360px) {
  .email-message br {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

use some ID or class to encapsulate it's effect inside the elements you specifically need, otherwise it will get rid of all `br` tags in mobile. If this is what you want, simply do:

```
@media(max-width: 360px) {
  br {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: @gaurav-kumar please if it solves your issue (it currently does) you need to mark the answer as accepted, clicking the tick and upvote.